# Not able to save video from share-extension ios

Tags: ios, video-processing, file-storage, ios-app-group

I have created a share-extension whose purpose is to share videos to my container app.
As part of the share flow i would like to check if user is logged in etc..
So i created an App Group and am sharing the data between the container app and the extension.( using both NSUserDefaults and Core Data)

```
 let  sharedUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName:"group.app.group.name")
lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.app.group.name")!
}()
```

This is working fine.

Now as i am trying to compress the video using [`SDAVAssetExportSession`](https://github.com/rs/SDAVAssetExportSession)

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH-mm-ss"
let timeStamp = NSDate()
let asset = AVAsset(URL: self.shareVideoURL)
let exportSession = SDAVAssetExportSession(asset: asset)
let outputURL = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(timeStamp)).MP4")
exportSession.outputURL = outputURL
exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

let assetTrack = asset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo).first!

let videoWidth:NSNumber = assetTrack.naturalSize.width, videoHeight:NSNumber = assetTrack.naturalSize.height, 
let desiredBitrate:NSNumber = 3*1024*1024 , desiredKeyFrameInterval:NSNumber = 20
exportSession.videoSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecH264,
    AVVideoWidthKey:videoWidth,
    AVVideoHeightKey:videoHeight,
    AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey: [
        AVVideoAverageBitRateKey:desiredBitrate,
        AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey:desiredKeyFrameInterval]]

exportSession.audioSettings = [AVFormatIDKey: NSNumber(unsignedInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
    AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
    AVEncoderBitRateKey: 64000]

exportSession.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({
    switch exportSession.status {
    case .Completed:
        print("Compressed Video size : \(Double(NSData(contentsOfURL: outputURL)!.length)/(1024*1024)) mb")
    case  .Failed:
        print("Export Failed :\(exportSession.error)")
    case .Cancelled:
        print("Export Cancelled :\(exportSession.error)")
    default:
        print("complete")
    }
})
```

When i execute this in the share-extension i am getting the error:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-3000 "Cannot create file" 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot create file, NSUnderlyingError=0x160900450 
{Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12149 "(null)"}}
```

When i run this code in another app using the document directory it is working fine without any problems, but when i start using the app group container it is not allowing to save the file.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to save the compressed file in the shared app group container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution for AVAssetExportSession and began to use AVAssetWriter directly, then also via [SDAVAssetExportSession](https://github.com/rs/SDAVAssetExportSession)

And seems like it works, it saves video. 
So, please check, that URL you are saving to is corresponding to [this.](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/77495#77495)

i rewrote Swift code from link to Objective-C

```
NSURL *groupPath = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: @"group.**.***"];
groupPath = [groupPath URLByAppendingPathComponent: @"Library" isDirectory: YES];
groupPath = [groupPath URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Caches" isDirectory: YES];
```

*code added after [Rao's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1702943/rao) comment*

Hope you'll solve this, keep me updated.

Answer (score 0):

Apps and Extensions do not have permission to write to the shared container itself but they do have permission to write into *"Library/Caches"* inside of that shared container.

For reference:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/45736